# Extended angular service

Tags: angularjs

I want to know what is the best approach to extend a method. For example, I want to create service to a datagrid implementation with 3 basic funcionalities (create, edit, delete). And then I want to create in all methods a callback function to get a row data and do a different flow.

This way, I can call this service and implement a lot of data grids with same functionalities but with different actions.

Comment: You can pass a callback function as a parameter to those CRUD methods in your service and call them after the method is finished. Does that work for you?

Comment: @YaserAdelMehraban Could you write an example for me?

Comment: Look up angularjs decorators. They are angulars built in way of extending injectable items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
app.service('datagridservice', function() {
    this.create = function (data, callback) {
        //do stuff here
        callback(/*any parameter you would like to have*/);
    }

    this.update = function (data, callback) {
        //do stuff here
        callback(/*any parameter you would like to have*/);
    }

    this.remove = function (data, callback) {
        //do stuff here
        callback(/*any parameter you would like to have*/);
    }
});


app.service('customiseddgsrv', ['datagridservice', function(datagridservice) {
    this.create = function (data) {
        datagridservice.create(data, function() {
            //do your service 2 stuff here
        });
    }

    this.update = function (data) {
        datagridservice.update(data, function() {
            //do your service 2 stuff here
        });
    }

    this.remove = function (data) {
        datagridservice.remove(data, function() {
            //do your service 2 stuff here
        });
    }
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's say `Service1` is the basic service, and `Service2` the extender. You just have to [inject](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di) `Service1` in `Service2` to access its methods:

```
.service('Service1', function() {
    this.create = function() {}
    this.edit = function() {}
    this.delete = function() {}          
});

.service('Service2', function(Service1) {
    var service1 = angular.copy(Service1);  

    service1.create = function() { /* New code here */ }
    service1.edit = function() { /* New code here */ }
    service1.delete = function() { /* New code here */ }          
});
```

Here I create a copy of `Service1` in `Service2` to not change the inherited service.

Comment: In this case, I want to preserve all methods from service1 and set a callback to change the flow on each method

Comment: You preserve methods from `Service1`: you just can call it from `Service1.create();`. Here `Service2` just give you the possibility to **rewrite in Service2** those methods.